# Можно ли совместить requests и discordpy?

Tags: python, requests, discord.py

Можно ли совместить requests и discordpy, чтобы сделать команду, которая берёт из заданного (мной в коде) сайта нужную инфу?

Answer (score -1):

Можно

```
response = requests.get('ссылка на апи')
await ctx.send(response.json())
```

Comment: Вы вызываете синхронный блокирующий код в асинхронной функции, сводя все преимущества асинхронного подхода на нет. Поставил минус, несмотря на то, что это работает

Comment: Вы не правы, мне просто нужно было показать, что это можно совместить с discord.py

Comment: [Посмотрите это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190403/how-could-i-use-requests-in-asyncio)

Comment: Придирка не в тему

Comment: @RAINGM Пожалуйста, все пояснения, аргументы в пользу вашего решения добавляйте в сам ответ. В текушем виде его лучше удалить.

Comment: @RAINGM В чём именно я не прав?

Comment: Пользователь задал вопрос, я ответил, к моему вопросу у него придирок не было. Значит он всё понял. Тема закрыта.